# Disable (GitGutter) message about commit on Sublime Text

Tags: git, plugins, sublimetext3, sublimetext, gutter

Sublime Text is showing a message about git commit.
It appears in the middle of source code but is not part of it and totally confuses myself. Its like an annotation and message reads like:

```
Commit author (a day ago) - Commit message
```

Please, how to remove that?

I'm pretty sure it comes from GitGutter package (https://jisaacks.github.io/GitGutter/settings/) because it stops appearing when I disable the package for view. But could not find any reference about this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `"show_line_annotation": "auto"` to `"show_line_annotation": false`.

There is section `Line Annotation` in document where you can edit template shown or disable it.